# Git reapply amended commit to a branch off of that commit

Tags: git, version-control

So say this is what my git history might look like:

```
m -> m
      \-> A
           \-> B
```

I branched off of mainline to create feature branch A and made a commit. Now I'm waiting for feature branch A to be approved, but I need to keep working and need feature A to work on feature B. So I make a new branch off of commit A and continue my work on B.

Say my code review comes back and says I need to make a change to A. To prevent pollution of the git history, I `git commit --amend` on A instead of making a new commit.

Now, since I've made changes in A, I need to make sure those changes are in branch B. So I switch to B do a `git rebase A`, but I end up with rebase conflicts.

Is there some way I simply apply the new changes I've amended into commit A into branch B without causing undue conflicts? I'm probably using the wrong command and shouldn't be using rebase, but I'm not sure what I should use.

Comment: It sounds like you did everything correctly. Are the conflicts real? Did you edit things in A that B also edits? If so, that's just par for the course. You might be able to use a tool like [`git rerere`](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere) to reapply the same change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Say my code review comes back and says I need to make a change to A. To prevent pollution of the git history, I `git commit --amend` on A instead of making a new commit.

That's all reasonable, but ... `git commit --amend` *makes a new commit*.

No one—not you, not anyone, not anything—can actually change any existing commit.

If we draw out each of the actual commits, one at a time, in the various branches, we get this as the initial picture:

```
...--o--o   <-- mainline
         \
          A1   <-- feature-A
           \
            B1--B2--B3   <-- feature-B
```

(assuming `feature-A` consists of one new commit, and `feature-B` consists of three).

You now are told to make some change to your `feature-A` so you run:

```
git checkout feature-A
```

to attach `HEAD` to `feature-A` and make `A1` the current commit.  You then make some change(s) to some file(s), copy those files into the index with `git add`, and run `git commit --amend` to make a new commit.

*Commit `A1` does not—**can** not—change.*  Instead, Git creates a new `A1'` that's like `A1` in that it has the same parent, but isn't `A1` because it has a different hash ID.  Git then makes your name, `feature-A`, point to the new commit.  Let's draw this, though it gets a little tricky:

```
          A1'  <-- feature-A (HEAD)
         /
...--o--o   <-- mainline
         \
          A1   [abandoned ... sort-of!]
           \
            B1--B2--B3   <-- feature-B
```

Now that there's no *name* attached to commit `A1`, there is no direct way to find it; but if we start at `B3` (the tip of `feature-B`) and work backwards, we find `B3`, then `B2`, then `B1`, then `A1`, and then the tip commit of `mainline`.

What this means is that commit `A1` is still there, still in use: it's just the first commit that's *only* on `feature-B`.  (`B1` through `B3` are likewise only on `feature-B`.)  `A1` used to be on *both* `feature-B` *and* `feature-A`; now it's only on `feature-B`.

When you go to copy `feature-B` so that it appends to `A1'`, you need to tell Git: *copy commits `B1` through `B3`*.  Git will normally copy `A1` through `B3`, because those are the commits that are (now!) only on `feature-B`.  To do this, you probably want `git rebase --onto`.  This allows you to separate the *what to copy* part of `git rebase` from the *where to put the copies* part of the operation:

```
git checkout feature-B
git rebase --onto feature-A feature-B~3
```

for instance.  This continues to assume that there are three commits to copy: `feature-B~2` (commit `B1`), `feature-B~1` (commit `B2`), and `feature-B` itself (commit `B3`).  If that's not the case, use something other than `feature-B~3` to identify the first commit *not* to copy.  (The raw hash ID of the original `A1` commit works well here, too.)